# Error while trying to install a nuget Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#, winforms, nuget

I'm actually coding a google Map application using Winforms, and I wanted to put markers on some places (I have their lat/long). So I tried to install the package Gds.googleMap.ultimate that seems to do what I need, but I always get this error:

> Unable to install the package "Gds.GoogleMap.Ultimate 4.0.28". You try to install this package in a project targeting ".NETFramework, Version = v4.5.2", but the package does not contain any content files or assembly references compatible with this framework. For more information, contact the creator of the package

Does someone have an idea of the problem, or should I use another tool for those markers?

Comment: I think your project may be targeting a version of .NET that is not compatible with the package.  Go to your project properties and make sure you're targeting .NET Framework 4.5.2 or higher.

Comment: The project is using the right .NET Framework (4.5.2) . I tried an older and most recent one and there still is the error. Besides I read that GDS was compatible with .Net 4.5.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I downloaded the package and it looks like it was not authored correctly.
The package would normally contain a directory structure like the following:

$root\lib\tfm

This package has a 
$root\V4.0.28 structure, which NuGet doesn't recognize.

More info https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/creating-a-package

You need to contact the owners of the package for this one.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the .net version to a lower version which support your nuget.

1. On the solution explorer right click on your project
2. properties
3. In the target framework tab choose .net 4.5.2

Comment: I tried it but it still doesn't work. By the way I read somewhere that this package is compatible with .net 4.5.2.